Extracting flow informations from switch using ryu controller
How to extract flow informations from switch (ip src ip dst protocol tcp port etc..)?
Ive tried extracting from flow stats reply like
this(flow.match[‘ipv4_src’]

I am using ryu controller

According to your question, information like ip_src can be extracted only from match field in OFPFlowStats. What's more, what you can extract depends on what the flow entries can match, and they are created by yourself.
For example, when using Layer 2 Switch with MAC learning, only eth_src, eth_dst and in_port are used to match packet in flow entries, while other fields are not used. So you cannot extract ip_src from these flow entries. If you want that, you need to use Layer 3 Switch with routing.
PS: OFPFlowStats also provides some counters information, which will be useful too.
